# Using cmake on windows without IDE

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

this might be a duplicate, but I've already spent a couple of hours searching for an answer... without solution. First of all I know this problem might not exist if I'd use a Linux, but I am on Windows.

I am pretty new to c++ but already got some experience with java and gradle. I try to use cmake just like I am used to use gradle. I already read the cmake wiki, but I either do not find the correct pages or I just don't understand it.  Here is my directory structure:

```
MyProject
-bin
-include
--header1.h
--header2.h
--header3.h
--header4.h
--header5.h
--header6.h
-src
--CMakeLists.txt
--MyProjectConfig.h.in
--impl1.cpp
--impl2.cpp
--impl3.cpp
--impl4.cpp
--impl5.cpp
--impl6.cpp
-main.cpp
-CMakeLists.txt
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` in my project folder looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.14)

project (MyProject)
add_subdirectory(src)

file(GLOB_RECURSE sources      src/*.cpp include/*.h)

# The version number.
set (Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set (Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR 1)


# configure a header file to pass some of the CMake settings
# to the source code
configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/MyProjectConfig.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/MyProjectConfig.h"
  )

# add the binary tree to the search path for include files
# so that we will find MyProjectConfig.h
include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")  

install (FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/MyProjectConfig.h"        
         DESTINATION include)

add_executable(MyProject main.cxx ${sources})

# add the install targets
install (TARGETS MyProject DESTINATION bin)
```

My CMakeLists.txt in the src folder looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.14)

include_directories(${MyProject_SOURCE_DIR}/MyProject/include)
```

I use the command in the bin bin directory: `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -S ../src`

I got 2 questions now:

1. (How do I tell cmake to always use MinGW? ( I don't want to use -G always)) solved
2. (The compiled file `build\CMakeFiles\3.14.0-rc2\CompilerIdCXX\a.exe` does not have the expected behavior. It should print "Hello world!" and "My Class", while "My Class" is printed from the attribute of a class created from `impl1.cpp`, however it does nothing.) needs clarification:
   **How do I build a windows .exe-file to ruin on the console?**

---

Edit:

I have learned that I have to call `cmake --build .` in my bin directory after creating the cmake files. However I just don't get an exe-file. With flag -v I get this output:

````
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -SD:\git\MyProject\src -BD:\git\MyProject\bin --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start D:\git\MyProject\bin\CMakeFiles D:\git\MyProject\bin\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/git/MyProject/bin'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/git/MyProject/bin'
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start D:\git\MyProject\bin\CMakeFiles 0 ```
````

Comment: getting started with c/c++ without using a IDE is really terrible experience, No matter what your platform is. And no linux doesn't make it any easier. I'm on linux, I've been struggling with these sort if issues, not for hours, but months, maybe also years if i count the time I've given up on this :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the -G option is the standard way of doing it. It prevents you from having to put system-specific settings into your CMake config (like the hardcoded paths to MingW) and lets you use other compilers without having to change build scripts.
2. The `a.exe` you started is not your build output. It should be called `MyProjectExec.exe`. Also, you need to specify all source files in your call to `add_executable`. `add_subdirectory` does not automatically add any source files (to what build output should it add them?), it just executes the CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This already helped a bit. However I still do not get an .exe-file to run my project. Right now it should just print out hello world on the console.

Comment: You're calling CMake for the CMakeLists.txt in the src directory. Try `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..`. As for building, `cmake --build .` is the generator-independent way of doing it, but you can also just call mingw32-make without any arguments.